# Where should I publish my formula related to Aufbau Principle?

Tags: orbitals

I have made a formula for determining the sequence of orbitals which is currently obtained using the Aufbau diagram. So, I wanted to know where should I publish it (if it is new). I searched the same on internet but did not get any such formula.

Comment: Hey there! It's nice to play around with ideas and discover new things. An important part of publishing is scoping the relevant background in the literature. This process alone can take months and often involves reading many dozens of articles, some often multiple times over. It seems you're still at too early a stage to consider publication. Do the reading, and you'll have a much better understanding of how to fit your work within our body of knowledge, including where you might be able to publish.

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto Thank You for your sincere help, and concern. Actually I am a student of 11th grade and I have to acquire lots of knowledge. But who knows this formula may be new, and may help in the subject. Although I have also heard about the limitations of Aufbau principle. But still we have to study it and this formula will help atleast me and my friends. Thank you once again for your concer.

Comment: No problem. I can even suggest a place to start. Eric Scerri has written multiple times about the aufbau principle, from a critical standpoint. Looking at his work, as well as the sources he cites, will give you a much broader view.

Comment: Better idea would be just write your ideas in question and see if they a) make sense b) aren't obvious c) are useful.

Comment: @AdityaAsthana As Mithoron set, if you write the idea here first, we can check if it makes sense/is useful. Also, if it does wind up being useful, there will be a visible record of when you came up with the idea in case someone else publishes similar work.

Comment: Yes  you both are right. I will post it tomorrow morning here in the comments. Thank You for your response.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you searched the Journal of Chemical Education? There are so many articles on this topic you are interested in. If you don't have access to formal databases, start from Google Scholar and read abstracts.

Journal of Chemical Education is the right platform for such "teaching" tricks. However, you have to justify with some theory as to why your idea works. What is the logic behind it? As far as I can recall (>10 years ago), there was an article by a high-school student in that journal. So, students can also publish but you have to be quite good at that subject - similar to a professional.

However, sometimes I receive such articles for review but the tricks or analogies are so horrible that there is no option but to reject them. Similarly, make sure you know where your approach fails. Can it predict the electron configuration of all the elements? If you are a student share the idea with a chemistry teacher. See their reaction (*no pun intended*). Do they find it useful or have they seen it before? If yes, certainly consider writing a short note.

Comment: Thank You sir for your kindly response. I have searched on Google Scholar for the same formula but did not get anything, even close to it. Would you mind telling me how to publish on Journal of Chemical Education? The least which will happen is that it will be rejected for not being something new. Thank You.

Comment: All you have to find now is an expert, who can give you more insight. What about your own college teacher to begin with?

Comment: Another possibly useful step is to consider writing a draft and submitting to a preprint server such as [ChemRxiv](https://chemrxiv.org/). The publishing sphere in Chemistry is slowly but surely moving towards accepting preprints, and indeed [this topic was specifically raised and defended](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jchemed.0c00169) by the now editor-in-chief of JCE, Thomas Holme.